# I have a question about markers on google map in androidф

Tags: java, android

I am writing applications in the Android studio in Java, and I have a question, how to add 15,000 markers on the google map, but so that the application does not hang, I am new to Android development

Comment: You don't.  Its not as if people could see 15K markers anyway.  You add only the ones that are relevant, and add/remove as things become or are no longer relevant.  If you're adding more than a dozen or two you're doing it wrong.

Comment: help me how to implement this